# Reinitialize static variable on new instance

Tags: php, class

Here is my problem, I'm using a static variable in a method. And I use a `for` loop to create new instance.

```
class test_for{

    function staticplus(){
        static $i=0;
        $i++;
        return $i;
    }

    function countplus() {
        $res = '';
        for($k=0 ; $k<3 ; $k++) {
            $res .= $this->staticplus();
        }
        return $res;
    }
}

for($j=0 ; $j<3 ; $j++) {
    $countp = new test_for;
    echo $countp->countplus().'</br>';
}
```

It returns:

```
123
456
789
```

Is there a way to initialize the static variable when creating new instance, so that is returns:

```
123
123
123
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like what you are asking for is the antithesis of a static variable. Rather, you want an instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand why do need this, but that behaviour can be achieved.
Try this:

```
class test_for{

protected static $st;        // Declare a class variable (static)

public function __construct(){ // Magic... this is called at every new
    self::$st = 0;           // Reset static variable
}

function staticplus(){
    return ++self::$st;
}

function countplus() {
    $res = '';
    for($k=0 ; $k<3 ; $k++) {
        $res .= $this->staticplus();
    }
    return $res;
}
}

for($j=0 ; $j<3 ; $j++) {
   $countp = new test_for;
   echo $countp->countplus().'</br>';
}
```

Comment: Why do you make `$st` a static var? It should be a simple `private $st=0` then you don't need the `__constructor()` at all.

Comment: @Michael Not the same, the static will stay set after all constructions are done and, additional obj->countplus() calls will set it higher cross objects (because it is a class var) which is a weird behaviour but which is also needed I guess.

Comment: @Michael After all if you just want a 123 you do not declare $i as static at staticplus in the example of the question.

Comment: It returns Parse error: parse error, expecting T_VARIABLE from this line protected static var $st;. When I use @Michael solution it works. But I also want to know why it is throwing this parse error?

Comment: Sorry, It is a stupid referencing problem. I corrected it now. Because I declared the static st as protected Php can not access it via public test_for reference.

Comment: @LostSEO By the way why do you want it static at all?

Comment: this is correct... but `__constructor` must be `__construct`, and `protected static var $st;` --> `protected static $st;`

Comment: @Laxus Thx for pointing out. ( omg var is deprecated ) Nowadays I am writing on multiple languages at the same time which causes this type of confusion...

Comment: @Ishan I used `static`, because I wasn't sure how I could keep the variable value through function iteration. Then I found out that there was a problem while looping through new instance. Actually when you wrote `protected static var`I was like, I have never seen this `var` before, it might be a trick ;) Anyway, thanks a lot for all of you guys!

Comment: @LostSEO If you want a variable surviving across functions, use an instance variable in aclass like public $x or protected $x private $x etc If you want a variable surviving across instances (objects of the class) use a static of class like public static $x or protected static $x private static $x etc. And declare all this in the class body not in a function body.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you res in a static variable maybe:

```
public res 

function countplus() {
    $this->res = 0;
    for($k=0 ; $k<3 ; $k++) {
        $this->res .= $this->staticplus();
    }
    return $this->res;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the problem is located on the static variable $i